Kafka HTTP Source connector - SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I am trying to use https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest connector to retrieve data from api.
I successfully built source code and installed plugin into Kafka Connect. But I cannot connect to api using https and get following error.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Connector configuration is following
  "name": "RestSourceConnectorSpring",
  "config": {
    "producer.compression.type": "snappy",
    "connector.class": "com.tm.kafka.connect.rest.RestSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "rest.source.poll.interval.ms": "10000",
    "rest.source.method": "GET",
    "rest.source.url": "https://myapi.testapi.com/subjects",
    "rest.source.headers": "Content-Type:application/json,Accept:application/json",
    "rest.source.topic.selector": "com.tm.kafka.connect.rest.selector.SimpleTopicSelector",
    "rest.source.destination.topics": "restSourceDestinationTopic"
  }
}

myapi.testapi.com has let's encrypt certificate and I can get required json data from browser.
How can I provide SSL configuration to retrieve data?
